# Xdebug doesn't work with sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, xdebug

- **Xdebug** installed on ubuntu 12.04 with sublime text build 3083 with help from this [Helpful article](http://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/)

  1. added necessary lines in *xdebug.ini* file

  zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
  xdebug.remote_enable=on
  xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
  xdebug.remote_host=localhost
  xdebug.remote_port=9500
  xdebug.show_local_vars=1
  xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"

  2. log file created on *var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log*
  3. installed [XdebugClient](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug) through package control in Sublime Text3
  4. create project folder **echo** on *var/www*

#### `Xdebug.sublime-settings`

```
{
    "path_mapping": {
        "/var/www/echo/" : "/var/www/echo/"
    },
    "url": "http://localhost/echo/index.php",
    "super_globals": true,
    "close_on_stop": true
}
```

echo.sublime-project

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "xdebug": {
            "path_mapping": {
                "/var/www/echo/" : "/var/www/echo/"
            },
            "url": "http://localhost/echo/index.php",
            "super_globals": true,
            "close_on_stop": true
        }
    }
}
```

5. create first php page

**index.php**

```
<?php   
  echo "hello world";  
  phpinfo(); 
?>
```

6. set breakpoint on first line
7. click **Tools > Xdebug Start Xdebug (launch browser)**

page opens in browser with prefix end with *?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug*

`http://localhost/echo/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug`

it show 4 panel in the bottom of sublime text3

BUT now how to step in step out?  it does not show anything in bottom panel

where am I missing any point ?

console output is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
>     File "./threading.py", line 858, in run
>     File "main in /home/keshav/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Xdebug Client.sublime-package", line 275, in listen
>     File "xdebug.protocol in /home/keshav/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Xdebug Client.sublime-package", line 250, in listen
>   Xdebug Client.xdebug.protocol.ProtocolConnectionException: [Errno 98] Address already in use

note: have seen [similar issue on github](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug/issues/63) but that does not help to resolve my issue.

Note: I have  but unable to see such panel (shown below) inside sublime text3 which was described in [another article](http://markonphp.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/) , 
[image: Xdebug install issue]

Comment: hey.. you must have solved the issue..but wandering for an hour i came to this thread and it really helped me to figure out my mistake..also not sure what was wrong with your's but simply using right click on any of panel in xdebug i was able to get step in and out options..

Answer (score -3):

1. Restart apache.
2. Change xdebug port number to avoid collision with web server port.

This will fix your issue.